# Create multiple new lists depending on number of items in another list

Tags: python, list

I've created a list which has 5 items, I've then created a `newlist` which is a path to a webpage using text and the item value from the list

I want to be able to loop through the items in `newlist` and create however many lists need creating based on the number of items in `newlist`

So ultimately 10 new lists in this example would be created:

```
buyers1
buyers2
buyers3
buyers4
buyers5
prices1
prices2
prices3
prices4
prices5
```

This works to loop through each webpage and print values but I can't refer to the lists outside (which are being overwritten each time anyway)

```
from lxml import html
import requests

list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
newlist = []
for l in list:
    newlist.append('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/00'+str(l)+'.html')

for n in newlist:
    page = requests.get(n)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
    prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')   
    for b in buyers :print(b)
    for p in prices :print(p)
```

but I can't then refer to these new list outside the for loop by adding this after (even though they are being overwritten each time anyway)

```
for b in buyers :print(b)
for p in prices :print(p)
```

so this is my attempt to create new lists but to no avail:

```
list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
value = 1
newlist = []
for l in list:
    newlist.append('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/00'+str(l)+'.html')

for n in newlist:
    page = requests.get(n)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    'buyers' + str(value) = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
    'prices' + str(value) = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')   
    value = value + 1
```

So ultimately I can reference the list later

```
for b in buyers1:
    print(b)
```

Comment: Have you read through the python docs on different data structures? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html  You would be better off using a more complex but flexible data structure, for example a list of dictionaries where each dictionary contains the buyer and price information.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you want to create new lists from buyers and prices? This might work -

```
newlist = ['http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/00'+str(i)+'.html' for i in range(1, 6)]
buyers, prices = [], []
for n in newlist:
    page = requests.get(n)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    buyers.append(tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
    prices.append(tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')
```

Now you can access `buyers` and `prices` outside the for loop. Let me know if I wrongly understood your question

Comment: Thanks thatbird, but I'm looking to create new lists for each iteration of buyer. So I need a list for each (buyer1, buyer2 etc)

Comment: In that case, a dict would be a good idea, but you can create lists for these too, but that will become list of list, is that okay? @Monkeydave

Comment: Marc is providing a dict solution so I'll try go with that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supposing I understood what the problem is, I Would suggest having a list of lists or a dictionary with values of type list, because not knowing the number of lists to expect, iterable objects are what you're looking for

Solution using a list :

```
from lxml import html
import requests

list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
newlist = []
listOfBuyers = []
listOfPrices = []
for l in list:
    newlist.append('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/00'+str(l)+'.html')

for n in newlist:
    page = requests.get(n)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
    prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')   
    for b in buyers :print(b)
    for p in prices :print(p)
    listOfBuyers.append(buyers)
    listOfPrices.append(prices)
```

Solution using dictionaries :

```
from lxml import html
import requests

list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
newlist = []
dictOfBuyers = {}
dictOfPrices = {}
for l in list:
    newlist.append('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/00'+str(l)+'.html')
i = 1
for n in newlist:
    page = requests.get(n)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
    prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')   
    for b in buyers :print(b)
    for p in prices :print(p)
    keyBuyers = "buyer" + str(i)
    keyPrices = "price" + str(i)
    dictOfBuyers[keyBuyers] = buyers
    dictOfPrices[keyPrices] = prices
    i += 1
```

For reading data from the dictionary, it is important to know that values in dictionaries are **not** indexed so we are going to need to read each value from its key like so :

```
for key, val in dictOfBuyers.items() :
    listBuyers = val
    listPrices = dictOfPrices["price" + key[-1]]

    print(listBuyers,"is corresponds to the prices",listPrices)
```

Comment: This dictionary solution looks to be on the lines of where I want to be, how do I refer to them going forward to call the contents of each list? Are dictionary values indexed so I can compare the nth value of buyers with the nth value in prices to ensure the right match?

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's great

Comment: You're most welcome. Could you please accept my solution?